# I need .htaccess code to redirect from /home to main page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am currently using Adobe Business Catalyst and looking for .htaccess code to redirect /home to /.

Currently using this below code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^54\.252\.148\.183

RewriteRule (.*) http://envirofrontier.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What is not working? I'm not seeing a question to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# For specific IP address(es), redirect the incoming request to /envirofrontier.com.au.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^54\.252\.148\.183
RewriteRule (.*) http://envirofrontier.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect /home to /
RewriteRule ^home/?$ / [R=302,L]
```

If you are happy with the redirect, you can change `R=302` to `R=301`.

In future, please show your attempts before asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That doesn't help. What's the *actual* problem?

Comment: I am looking to redirect envirofrontier.com.au/home to http://envirofrontier.com.au.

Comment: Does your `.htaccess` file belong to envirofrontier.com.au? In other words, is it saved in the document root of that domain? If not, where is it saved?

Comment: It is saved in the root of the domain.

Comment: Then I don't quite understand what the first condition and rule is for. Also, you are not being very clear with me, so I cannot help you, I'm afraid.